# Creating Job Schedules in Azure Batch

Tags: java, azure, azure-batch

I am trying to create a job schedule in the azure batch. But when ever I create a job schedule, instantly my job inside the job schedule starts deleting with exit code 130:

> Ended task on user request.

I am not able to figure out why this is happening and why I am not able to create job schedules.

Comment: I did not find the error code 130 from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/batchservice/batch-status-and-error-codes. Would you please post more details about your trace log. You could find the logs in stderr.txt and stdout.txt files on portal.

Comment: The task is not reaching the pool as there are no stderr or stdout files generated, the job is instantly getting deleted as soon as I create it with exit code 130 . The message that comes in task is 

 Task failed "Task Was Ended by User Request"

and the exit code of the task is set to be 130.

Comment: According to the link I mentioned above , "Task Was Ended by User Request"  is TaskEnded Error code. You could refer to the Error handling from this link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-api-basics.

Comment: How are you looking at the job to see what is happening? If you haven't already, try inspecting the job with [BatchLabs](https://github.com/Azure/BatchLabs) and looking at the error details listed on the task. (BatchLabs provides the most detailed viewpoint.)

Comment: I tried with Batch Labs , I got two messages there
One is 
BlobNotFound
One of the specified Azure Blob(s) is not found. 
and the other is 
Container name format is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you so much @Bevan. Batch Labs really helped . I got more details on the error and was successfully able to resolve it . The error was with resource file. I uploaded it afresh and it worked . Many thanks